# Alt Tags not working on my site

Tags: image, tooltip, alt

I am trying to figure out why alt image tags are not working on my site www.slickcar.com. I have reviewed the alt= tag and it looks correct but when I look at in the IE, Chrome or Firefox they do not display when I hover over the images.

Comment: What do the tags look like? Can you post the HTML here?

Comment: Use `title` attribute. `title="Samsung"`

Comment: The Tags look like this  <tr>
                                      <td><img src="accessories/images/logos/logo_volkswagen.gif" width="30" height="16" alt="Volkswagen Accessories"></td>
                                        <td nowrap class="NormalSmall" style="font-size:13px;"><a href="http://www.slickcar.com/all_volkswagen_accessories.asp">Volkswagen Accessories</a></td>
                                      </tr>

Answer (score 3):

The `alt` attribute is not meant to be a tooltip. It serves as *text alternative* to the image, e.g. for screen reader or text browser users, search engines etc. The value of the `alt` attribute should describe the content (= the image), so that someone can understand the meaning/purpose of the image without seeing it.

The value of the `title` attribute is typically shown as tooltip. It should give *additional* (and not alternative) information.